# How to Change Font in ICSharp TextEditor?

Tags: c#

I would like to ask you how to change font in ICSharp TextEditor in C#.Net.
I'm from Thai.So i want to show my language in ICSharp TextEditor.
I also changed font property in Property box,but it doesn't effect .
Its only show square.
How can i do that..

Thanks you for your time...

Comment: Have you tried setting the TextEditorControlBase.Font property in code instead?

Comment: yes... i get it..and also i want to clear all text from TextEditor..
So i used txtEditor.Text=""; But its doesn't work..How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it seems that setting the font needs to be done in code:

```
textEditorControl1.Font = new Font("Courier New", 8.25f, FontStyle.Regular);
```

And for clearing the text, I use the following helper method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets the text and refreshes the control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">The text.</param>
public void SetTextAndRefresh(string text)
{
    ResetText();
    Text = text;
    Refresh();
}
```

For a modified ICSharp TextEditor see [this project on github](https://github.com/StefH/ICSharpCode.TextEditorEx).